# cross page posting asp.net not returning values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web form as

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server" Text="Post on Next Page"/>
<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Page2.aspx" Text="Post on next page" />
```

Now on `Page2.aspx` the code-behind is as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(PreviousPage!=null && PreviousPage.IsCrossPagePostBack)
   {
       TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("txtname");
       label1.Text = "Value: " + txt1.Text;
   }
}
```

I end up getting the error `object reference not set to instance of an object` for `txt1`

Where `label1` is a label used to display the output. However, the value is not displayed.

What step am i missing?

Comment: What is PreviousPage here? Also, are you getting a value for txt1 ?

Comment: PreviousPage is Page1.aspx which has the above form. When I debug, no value gets stored for txt1

Comment: `txtname` isn't contained within another container is it? To test this , on Page1.aspx.cs can you type `this.txtname` and get the TextBox object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if (PreviousPage != null && PreviousPage.IsCrossPagePostBack)
            {
                //get the content place holder from master page of your previous page where your controls are placed
                //In this code the txtname textbox is placed inside ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent"
                var cp =PreviousPage.Master.FindControl("MainContent") as ContentPlaceHolder;
                //find the textbox inside content place holder from previous page
                TextBox txt1 = cp.FindControl("txtname") as TextBox;
                label1.Text = "Value: " + txt1.Text;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that PostBackURL is valid on a Textbox? Normally this attribute is attached to something that submits, such as a Button or LinkButton, eg:

```
<form runat="server">
  Name:<asp:textbox id="TextBox1" runat=Server />
  <asp:button id="Button1" Text="Submit"
  PostBackUrl="demo_postbackurl.aspx" runat="Server" />
</form>
```

Edit: Aha! - you do use a button.

Your code looks OK to me.

If the TextBox is within another control FindControl might not find it - if (for example) it's within a Panel you would need to do something like

```
TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)PreviousPage.MyPanel.FindControl("txtname");
```

If it's not within another control then I'm afraid I don't know.

Comment: sorry about that. Yes there is a button and the button has the PostBackUrl. However the value does not get passed.

Comment: I am actually using a master page and content pages. So this entire form is embedded inside <asp:Content ID="content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="contentplaceholder1" runat="server" />